Where is the scope of each Stack Exchange site displayed?
I am struggling to find the scope of the Stack Exchange sites.
It really should be displayed right on the welcome page / home page of each site (but it isn't). This would guide users and contribute to keeping questions within the site's scope.
All I could find is a short title in the all sites overview. Example:

Server Fault: Q&A for system and network administrators
Super User: Q&A for computer enthusiasts and power users

I assume and hope there is a longer description with a more detailed definition of the scope somewhere?
If I look just at the example given, all Super User Qs could also be asked in Server Fault, since all "system and network admins" are also (a subset of) "computer enthusiasts and power users".
Besides, the scope of acceptable questions would be better defined by defining the acceptable range of topics (rather than the pool of people who should ask or answer). If available, where can I find it?

I'm always a little surprised by this: there is a clear question mark button right on top of the page, which can easily be spotted, and would be a clear starting point, especially when one is not sure what kind of website they landed on. As your answer points out, this is also where all the necessary information can easily be found. Nevertheless, a lot of users struggle with it (yes, yes :), so making this clearer would be better.

Related Why doesn't the homepage of SE sites explain what the site is for?

Ok, I think I just stumbled upon the required information (rather than via a helpful link on the home page):
Apparently the scope of each site is defined in the help pages:

https://superuser.com/help/on-topic
https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic
https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

I assume this is the place to go.
Or is the scope also displayed elsewhere?

That's probably the best place to start. Also look at what not to ask.

/help/on-topic and /help/dont-ask on each site cover most of the scope you're looking for.

Also, each site has a /tour page that describes in brief both the site's scope and the Stack Exchange model.

Also on the Ask Question page (on the right, except for Stack Overflow, on which two(?) of the three variants of the Ask Question page don't have it there).
